# Select messages where author is marked as "allow others to see that user's commets"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm looking at switching to MongoDB at some point for some of my projects. For that to happen I need to test it and know what I can and what I can't do.

After reading some books about how does MongoDB works I must say I'm a little bit confused about how does actually the `select`'s work.

Let's say I have a collection called `users`:

```
{
    user_name: string,
    ....,
    ....,
    messages_can_be_seen_by_others: boolean
}
```

also, I have a collection of `topics`:

```
{
    topic_title: string,
    .....,
    .....,
    topic_messages:
        [
            {
                 user_name: string,
                 text: string,
                 date: DateTime
            },
            {
                 user_name: string,
                 text: string,
                 date: DateTime
            }
        ]
    .....
}
```

How can I select one topic and all it's messages according to the `users` collection?
I mean, a message writen by the person `Person1` who does not have the `messages_can_be_seen_by_others` marked as `true` should not be returned by the database.

So, should I use map/reduce, filter with `php` once I have all the results, or is there any other thing I'm not aware of?
In case I should use map/reduce how difficult could it be?

Also, there's another question. How can I select all the fields from `topics` and the `date` from the first message? (Something like `$elemMatch.messages.0.date`)

PS: Extra question: Can I return the number of messages that a topic has? (without actually counting them using PHP. Just plan MongoDB select statement)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your questions can more or less be solved with the new [Aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), that ships with the 2.2 version of MongoDB (released today!).

One caveat though: Aggregation only works on a single collection. In your first question, if you want to combine the information from the users collection (in particular, the `messages_can_be_seen_by_others` flag) with the information from the topics collection (i.e. the messages), you need to use either Map/Reduce, make an additional query beforehand to check if you want that user included in the following query, or simply store the whole user document with the topics, rather than just the name. This is something you wouldn't do with RDBMS but for document based databases like MongoDB, this is quite common practice.

Aside from that, all your problems can be solved by aggregation. For example

1. Select a topic and all the messages from a particular user can be done with this syntax:

   ```
   db.topics.aggregate(
       {$match: {'topic_title':'Some Topic Title'}}, 
       {$unwind: '$topic_messages'}, 
       {$match: {'topic_messages.user_name': 'Some User Name'}}, 
       {$group: {'_id':'$topic_title', 'messages': {$addToSet: '$topic_messages'}}}
   )
   ```

   This query would first filter only the topics that match the title, then unwind (opposite of group) the messages, filter for a certain user, and finally group the messages back together according to their title.
2. Find all topic titles and the date of their first (earliest) message:

   ```
   db.topics.aggregate(
       {'$unwind': '$topic_messages'}, 
       {'$sort': {'topic_messages.date' : 1}}, 
       {'$group': {'_id': '$topic_title', 
                   'first_date': {'$first': '$topic_messages.date' }
                  }
       }
   )
   ```
3. Count all the messages for one topic (with MongoDB, not php):

   ```
   db.topics.aggregate(
       {'$match': {'topic_title': 'Some Topic Title'}}, 
       {'$unwind': '$topic_messages'}, 
       {'$group': {'_id':'$topic_title', 'count': {$sum: 1}}}
   )
   ```

So you see, the Aggregation framework is quite powerful, and even works over sharded collections, as long as all the information you require is stored in a single collection.

Comment: Thank you! MongoDB looks really interesting, but I'll stick with MySQL for my projects for now and keep playing with MongoDB until I feel more confortable.